# Adjacency list and using Depth First Search

Tags: ios, objective-c, depth-first-search

This is a bidirectional graph of connected stands

```
 STAND_ID_FK    CONNECTED_STAND DISTANCE_BETWEEN_STAND  TIME_BETWEEN_STAND
    101              102              1                      2
    102              103            0.8                    1.5
    103              104            1.4                      2 
    104              105            1.007                    2
    105              106            1.264                    2
    106              107            0.8                    1.5
```

I want to create a adjacency list or list that suits best for graph representation. i am confused can I do this by `NSMutableArray` if yes then how? And then i have to imply dfs in the graph to traverse shortest path through the list from any given source to destination  like 102 to 106 or 108 to 103

Answer (score 1):

You can find better resources online but here's a basic implementation of Graph, Vertex and DFS in Objective-C:

**Graph.h**

```
@interface Graph : NSObject

-(instancetype)initWithVertex:(Vertex*)vertex;
-(void)addVertexFrom:(Vertex*)fromVertex toVertex:(Vertex*)toVertex;
-(void)printAdjacencyList;
-(void)bfs:(Vertex*)root;
-(void)dfs:(Vertex*)root;

@end
```

**Graph.m**

```
@interface Graph()

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary<Vertex*, NSMutableArray<Vertex*>*> *adjacencyList;

@end

@implementation Graph

-(instancetype)initWithVertex:(Vertex*)vertex
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.adjacencyList = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        [self addVertexFrom:vertex toVertex:nil];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)addVertexFrom:(Vertex*)fromVertex toVertex:(Vertex*)toVertex
{
    Vertex *fromV = [self isVertexPresent:fromVertex];

    if (fromV)
    {
        NSMutableArray *adjacentVertices = _adjacencyList[fromV];
        [adjacentVertices addObject:toVertex];
    }
    else
    {
        [_adjacencyList setObject:toVertex ? [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:toVertex] : [NSMutableArray new] forKey:fromVertex];
    }
}

-(Vertex*)isVertexPresent:(Vertex*)vertex
{
    for (Vertex *v in _adjacencyList.allKeys)
    {
        if ([v isEqual:vertex])
        {
            return v;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}

-(void)printAdjacencyList
{
    NSMutableString *graphDesciption = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    for (Vertex *v in _adjacencyList.allKeys)
    {
        [graphDesciption appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@ -> ", v.data]];

        for (Vertex *adjV in _adjacencyList[v])
        {
            [graphDesciption appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, ", adjV.data]];
        }

        [graphDesciption appendString:@"\n"];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", graphDesciption);
}

-(void)bfs:(Vertex*)root
{
    NSMutableArray *queue = [NSMutableArray new];
    [queue addObject:root];

    while (queue.count)
    {
        Vertex *curr = [queue objectAtIndex:0];
        [queue removeObjectAtIndex:0];

        if (curr.state != Visited)
        {
            curr.state = Visited;
            NSLog(@"\n%ld", (long)curr.data.integerValue);
            NSArray *temp = _adjacencyList[curr];
            for (Vertex *v in temp)
            {
                [queue addObject:v];
            }
        }
    }
}

-(void)dfs:(Vertex*)root
{
    if (root == nil) return;

    NSLog(@"\n%ld", (long)root.data.integerValue);
    root.state = Visited;

    for (Vertex *v in _adjacencyList[root])
    {
        if (v.state != Visited)
        {
            [self dfs:v];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Here's an example of how you would use it in **main.m**:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        Vertex *vertex0 = [[Vertex alloc] initWithIndex:@(0) data:@(0)];
        Vertex *vertex1 = [[Vertex alloc] initWithIndex:@(1) data:@(1)];
        Vertex *vertex2 = [[Vertex alloc] initWithIndex:@(2) data:@(2)];
        Vertex *vertex3 = [[Vertex alloc] initWithIndex:@(3) data:@(3)];
        Vertex *vertex4 = [[Vertex alloc] initWithIndex:@(4) data:@(4)];
        Vertex *vertex5 = [[Vertex alloc] initWithIndex:@(5) data:@(5)];

        Graph *graph = [[Graph alloc] initWithVertex:vertex0];

        [graph addVertexFrom:vertex0 toVertex:vertex1];
        [graph addVertexFrom:vertex0 toVertex:vertex4];
        [graph addVertexFrom:vertex0 toVertex:vertex5];

        [graph addVertexFrom:vertex1 toVertex:vertex3];
        [graph addVertexFrom:vertex1 toVertex:vertex4];

        [graph addVertexFrom:vertex2 toVertex:vertex1];

        [graph addVertexFrom:vertex3 toVertex:vertex2];
        [graph addVertexFrom:vertex3 toVertex:vertex4];

        [graph dfs:vertex0];

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Like I said, you can easily create your own solution as there is an excellent amount of material out there on Graphs. I have given only one way of doing it.